# How to get exhaustive list of android permissions at Runtime?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am trying to get exhaustive list of all possible permission available in public final class Manifest.permission using Java reflection.

Class permission = Class.forName("android.Manifest.permission");

but getting ClassNotFoundException.

Can anyone suggest where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like that:
`Class permission = android.Manifest.permission.class;` It works for me in my android project and I think it is also a bit neater that way. You will get the error (if there is such) compile time, not runtime which is also a benefit.

**EDIT** The reason why your approach will not work: the `android.Manifest.permission` class belong to different class loader. I have made the following experiment:

```
Log.i("Tag", "" + android.Manifest.permission.class.getClassLoader());
Log.i("Tag", "" + this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

The result was:

```
INFO/Tag(281): java.lang.BootClassLoader@4001bde0
INFO/Tag(281): dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.company.android-2.apk]
```

As soon as the two classes have different class loader, the `Class.forName` will not return the class of the other one.

Comment: Thanks Boris....worked like a charm but still wondering why Class.forName didn't work out?